# User Input Box to provide sheet name for code to use as source

Tags: excel, vba, user-input

been browsing through a few user input/sheet name related posts but none fit what I am looking for.
I have a simple code that will select columns based on preset criteria. Currently the code is pointing to a fixed sheet name. I want the code to open a input box, the user selects any cell on the source sheet and then the code will specify ws = worksheets("desiredSheetname")

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, lastRow As Long
Dim myNamedRange As Range, Rng As Range, c As Range, destrange As Range
Dim myRangeName As String
Dim SearchRow As Long
Dim StartatRow As Long
Dim desiredSheetName As String

desiredSheetName = Application.InputBox("Select any cell inside the source sheet: ", _
"Prompt for selecting target sheet name", Type:=8).Worksheet.Name


Set ws = Sheet.desiredSheetName  ------ error object required

lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

.....
```

Any idea how to write the ws line to have the correct sheet name linked?

Comment: `Set ws Sheets(desiredSheetName)`?.. `Set ws = Application.InputBox("...", Type:=8).Worksheet`?..

Comment: Side note, you should handle run-time error 9 if/when the `desiredSheetName` doesn't exist in the active workbook.

Comment: Curious why you know you want `ws = worksheets("desiredSheetname")` but you're not showing code that does it. You're looking for `Set ws = worksheets(desiredSheetname)`, which is pretty close (just drop the quotes to pass a variable's value rather than a string literal containing a variable's name, and use `Set` for the assignment).

Answer (score 0):

### Reference a Worksheet Via Application InputBox Range

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub WorksheetFromInput()

    ' Allow hitting enter if the appropriate cell was already selected.
    Dim aibDefault As String
    If TypeOf Selection Is Range Then aibDefault = Selection.Address
    
    Dim rg As Range
    
    On Error Resume Next
        Set rg = Application.InputBox( _
            Prompt:="Select any cell inside the source sheet: ", _
            Title:="Prompt for selecting target sheet name", _
            Default:=aibDefault, _
            Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If rg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "You canceled.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = rg.Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    MsgBox "Name: " & ws.Name & vbLf & "LastRow: " & LastRow, vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

You could get rid of `Application.InputBox` in the following way:

```
Sub WorksheetFromSelection()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = Selection.Parent
    On Error GoTo 0

    If ws Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No worksheet selected."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    MsgBox "Name: " & ws.Name & vbLf & "LastRow: " & LastRow, vbInformation

End Sub
```